# Get new data frame based on two DataFrames with relationships

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am sure this is way easier than I am making this out to be.  In df1 I have a list of column names with their location.  In df2 I have data for for each location.  Now I want a new dataframe (df3) that is 5 columns, with P1-P5 as columns names, by 10 rows.  Essentially, df3 will be based on the "name" and "location" relationships in df1. In this case P2-P3 and P4-P5 will have the same data in their columns, respectively.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4','P5'],
                 'Location': ['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Loc2', 'Loc3','Loc3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
"Loc1": np.random.rand(10),
"Loc2": np.random.rand(10),
"Loc3": np.random.rand(10),})

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Do I need to merge these to get this to work?  I cannot seem to get this to work...

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner').dropna()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
df3=df2[df1.Location]
df3.columns=df1.Name
print(df3)
```

which returns a dataframe in the requested format:

```
Name        P1        P2        P3        P4        P5
0     0.989912  0.294179  0.294179  0.963934  0.963934
1     0.804264  0.477704  0.477704  0.029615  0.029615
2     0.515048  0.641308  0.641308  0.543894  0.543894
3     0.956839  0.490116  0.490116  0.036772  0.036772
4     0.914164  0.681606  0.681606  0.201012  0.201012
5     0.616189  0.211699  0.211699  0.815522  0.815522
6     0.372732  0.132955  0.132955  0.995578  0.995578
7     0.371434  0.278308  0.278308  0.532968  0.532968
8     0.521310  0.101441  0.101441  0.712489  0.712489
9     0.669819  0.970496  0.970496  0.390313  0.390313
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sense to me!  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Just FYI, when I adopted this to my workflow, I had columns names that had gaps so I did the following: `df3=df2[df1['Location']]` and `df3.columns=df1['Name']`